# Barcode is not shown in print preview.(Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a pdf containing some barcodes.
In WKWebView the pdf preview is fine(Barcodes are shown).
But in the print Preview barcodes are not coming.

Here is the code I am using.

```
#define kPrintingPerPageEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 40, 60, 40)

- (void)presentPrintInteractionControllerWithFormatter:(UIPrintFormatter *)printFormatter
                                               jobName:(NSString *)jobName
                                           contentType:(PrintingContentType)contentType
                              actionSheetBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
                                 printInfoOrientation:(UIPrintInfoOrientation) printOrientation
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController = [[self class] createPrintInteractionControllerWithJobName:jobName];
    printInteractionController.printFormatter = printFormatter;
    printInteractionController.printFormatter.perPageContentInsets = kPrintingPerPageEdgeInsets;
    printInteractionController.printInfo.orientation = printOrientation;
    [self presentPrintInteractionController:printInteractionController
                                contentType:contentType
                              barButtonItem:barButtonItem];
}

+ (UIPrintInteractionController *)createPrintInteractionControllerWithJobName:(NSString *)jobName
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printInteractionController.printingItem = nil;
    printInteractionController.printFormatter = nil;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = jobName;
    printInteractionController.printInfo = printInfo;

    return printInteractionController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the solution by myself.
Instead of using printFormatter we can use PrintingItem property of printInteractionController to print the document.

```
printInteractionController.printFormatter = nil;
printInteractionController.printingItem = pdfData;
```

pdfData is the NSData related to the pdf.